# How to upload video/audio in nopCommerce?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I want to upload video/images in nopCommerce 2.3 . I already display video by embed through html , video is uploaded on youtube. But I want to upload video/audio to nopCommerce by administration section. Then display video and audio in product details page in frontend.

Is there any extension for it ?

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.